A man buys a dozen pieces of fruit...Questions about finding which solutions work
From Dudley's Elementary Number Theory, Section 3 on Linear Diophantine Equations, he poses the problem "A man bought a dozen pieces of fruit--apples and oranges--for 99 cents. If an apple costs 3 cents more than an orange, and he bought more apples than oranges, how many of each did he buy?"
Setting up the equations is straightforward. Let $a$ be the number of apples, $o$ be the number of oranges, and $p$ be the price of an orange in cents. Then:
$a+o=12$
$(p+3)a+po=99$
Where $6<a\le 12$. Eliminating $o$ from the equations I get:
$3a+12p=99$
Which simplifies to:
$a+4p=33$
Next I want to find one solution to this system. So I choose $p=6$, then $a=9$, and $o=3$.
Now I construct the general solution:
$a=9+t$
$o=3-t$
$p=(33-a)/4$
I can proceed from here to use different values for $t$ to evaluate other solutions. None of the other solutions (using $t=1$, $t=2$, $t=-1$, and $t=-2$) gave a valid result for p (which needs to be a whole number). So, there is only one solution.
My question is: once I construct the general solution (if I did it correctly) is trial and error the only way to determine whether any other solution is valid? Seems clunky.

This is already explained in the answer to your prior question. You should ask for elaboration there before posting another question.

You want to find $t$ such that $9+t$, $3-t$ and $(33-a)/4 = (24-t)/4 = 6-t/4$ are nonnegative integers, and $9 + t > 3 - t$ so $t > -3$.  For the first two, you need $t$ to be an integer with $-9 \le t \le 3$.  For the last, you need $t$ to be divisible by $4$ and $t \le 24$.  The only multiple of $4$ between $-2$ and $3$ is $0$, because $-2 > (-1)\cdot 4$ while $3 < 1 \cdot 4$.
